# Getting the position of the max element from a 2D array except for a specific column

Tags: python

I am trying to implement Q-Learning, and I need to get the position of the max element from a 2D array (the so-called Q-Value matrix) except for the sixth column (column index 5), similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62485600/6828329). I tried to implement the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62485694/6828329). My implementation, and the output, is as follows:

```
        print("The current self.q_values is")
        print(self.q_values)
        col = 1
        print("col is: " + str(col))
        row, column = np.unravel_index(self.q_values[:, :col].argmax(), self.q_values[:, :col].shape) # left max, saving a line assuming its the global max
        right_max = np.unravel_index(self.q_values[:, col + 1:].argmax(), self.q_values[:, col + 1].shape)
        if self.q_values[right_max] > self.q_values[row, column]:
            row, column = right_max
            column += col
        self.current_action = np.argmax(self.q_values[row, column])



The current self.q_values is
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
col is: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
    if self.q_values[right_max] > self.q_values[row, column]:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The Q-Value matrix was initialised as follows:

```
# Q-values for each combination of state and action.
# rows represent states, columns represent actions
self.q_values = np.zeros((100, 5))
```

I'm struggling to understand exactly what the code is doing, so I can't figure out how to do it correctly. I would usually just use the following:

```
        self.current_action = np.argmax(self.q_values[self.current_state - 1])
```

But, in cases where `np.argmax(self.q_values[self.current_state - 1])` is 5 (in other words, the current action is that which is represented by column 5 of q_values), I need to abandon column 5 and just check columns 0 to 4. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Typo: you have forgotten the colon `:` in  `self.q_values[:, col + 1].shape` (should be `self.q_values[:, col + 1:].shape`)

Comment: @Claudio Thanks for that! Do I just replace `col = 1` with `col = 5`? It isn't clear to me exactly what needs to be changed for my purpose.

Comment: In case of the last column in the array there will be no right side, so you don't need with col=5 the `right_max` and the `if`. So `row, column = np.unravel_index(self.q_values[:, :col].argmax(), self.q_values[:, :col].shape)` will be sufficient.

Comment: @Claudio So instead of `self.current_action = np.argmax(self.q_values[self.current_state - 1])`, I just have `col = 5` and then `row, column = np.unravel_index(self.q_values[:, :col].argmax(), self.q_values[:, :col].shape)`, so that we get                 `self.current_action = np.argmax(self.q_values[row - 1])`? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: You have asked how to find indices of a maximum value in a 2D-numpy-array skipping a column from consideration because you run into an error message. The question about `self.current_action =` is another one, so I suggest you ask another question about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing what follows you will be able to understand what the code actually does:

Numpy `argmax` method returns the index of the first found maximum value in an array `q_values` as index to the flattened array ( see [numpy docu on argmax](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) ). So if you want the row, column indices to the max value in the array `q_values` it is necessary to use the `np.unravel_index` method to obtain them from the index to the flattened array.

With this above you can then see yourself that the error message you have got was caused by a missing colon in `self.q_values[:, col + 1].shape` (should be `self.q_values[:, col + 1:].shape`).

In your special case of skipping the very last column there is no need to split the search to a left and right side of the column to skip, so using:

```
        col = 5
        row, column = np.unravel_index(self.q_values[:,:col].argmax(), self.q_values[:, :col].shape)
```

will give you already the required indices.

*But, in cases where np.argmax(self.q_values[self.current_state - 1]) is 5 (in other words, the current action is that which is represented by column 5 of q_values), I need to abandon column 5 and just check columns 0 to 4. What is the correct way to do this?*

```
np.argmax(self.q_values[self.current_state - 1, :5])
```

Comment: In the case of using `self.current_action = np.argmax(self.q_values[self.current_state - 1])`, the `argmax` would just get the column index of the highest value in row `self.current_state - 1` of `self.q_values`. So, in this case, what I'm looking for is `column` in your answer, right? So, just to be confirm, this solution basically ignores column 5, even if it contains the highest value, and instead goes for the highest value in columns 0-4, right? But the row would still be the same, right?

Comment: Yes, it goes for the highest value in columns 0-4, but for ALL rows giving the row and the column of the first max-value found. And no, you are not looking for column in my answer, because if you want to look for the column index with the maximum value for a given row you don't need that search at all, so I suggest to use `self.current_action = np.argmax(self.q_values[self.current_state - 1, :col])`